# The query is receiving two values from URL but not working

Tags: php

Hello i m receiving two values from the URL and used in in a query its not working and also

i have used mysql_error(); in the query but not showing any error.

The values are receiving to me but i m unable to use them in query to perform the action.

here is the code:

```
<?php

require_once('../db.php');

$status =  $_GET['Status'];

$propertyID = $_GET['PropertyID'];


if($status == 'Active')
{
    $connection->query("UPDATE properties SET Status='Inactive' WHERE  PropertyID='$propertyID'") or mysql_error();
}
else
{
    $connection->query("UPDATE properties SET Status='Active' WHERE  PropertyID='$propertyID'") or mysql_error();
}


?>
```

Comment: please share with us your form

Comment: I suggest using boolean values for `Status` instead of varchar and and type cast `(int)$propertyID`

Comment: You should remove the single quotes from the value when using in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values arrives and you don't get any error, probably it's because the $_GET value in the query is not converted. try this:

```
"UPDATE properties SET Status='Inactive' WHERE  PropertyID='{$propertyID}'"
```

or

```
"UPDATE properties SET Status='Inactive' WHERE  PropertyID='".$propertyID."'"
```

Comment: sorry both not worked. when ever im echo these two values so its printing but its not coming in query

Comment: try to echo ""UPDATE properties SET Status='Inactive' WHERE  PropertyID='$propertyID'" and use it directly in your db (by console or managers like phpmyadmin).. does it work? if so, something goes wrong in your database connection or query executer